# Need a little help while trying to add html.actionLink to a Jquery Datatable

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I'm a little confused, I'm trying to use a jQuery datatable in my ASP.NET MVC application but I was not able to add the EDIT or DELETE buttons

This is what I'm trying to convert:

```
<td>
@Html.ActionLink("EDIT", "Edit", new { id = item.code })    
</td>
```

I am trying to use a DATATABLE grid.

This is my whole Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Approvers>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Approver";
}

<h1>Approver</h1>

<table class="table" id="Exampledatatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CODE)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FIRSTNAME)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CODE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FIRSTNAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESCRIPTION)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.23/af-2.3.5/datatables.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.23/af-2.3.5/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Exampledatatable').DataTable({

                
                 "mDataProp": function (source, type, val) {
                     return '<a href= "/Home/Edit" + source.><>'
            }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

How i am supposed to convert that?

Comment: What do you mean by not able to?

Comment: You can add td manually.  In `<thead>` put an emty `<th>`. Then in `foreach`  you can add 
`
<td>
     @Html.ActionLink("EDIT", "Edit", new { id = item.code })    
</td>
`
So you can use like `$('#Exampledatatable').DataTable()`

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying. I've been searching and i found this: mRender: function (data, type, row) {} but was not able to make it work :/

Comment: Yeah, i tried that but it is not displaying the EDIT button

Comment: If i put <td>
@Html.ActionLink("EDIT", "Edit", new { id = item.code })    
</td> then the DATABASE GRID stop working

Comment: Did you try add link in `<td>` manually like this : `<a href="/Home/Edit/@item.code">EDIT ROW</a>`

Comment: If i put this <td> @Html.ActionLink("EDIT", "Edit", new { id = item.code }) </td>  then i can see the EDIT button but the DATATABLE stop working